# How do I edit the url in python and open a new page without having a new window or tab opened?

Tags: python, browser

I am trying to create a python script that opens a single page at a time, however python + mozilla make it so everytime I do this, it opens up a new tab.  I want it to keep just a single window open so that it can loop forever without crashing due to too many windows or tabs.  It will be going to about 6-7 websites and the current code imports time and webbrowser.

webbrowser.open('url')
time.sleep(100)
webbrowser.open('next url')

//but here it will open a new tab, when I just want it to change the page.

Any information would be greatful,

Thank you.

Comment: Its not python's fault. Firefox does not allow 3rd-party apps to arbitrarily control its content. It provides command line option to open new tab or window, but thats all.

Comment: Ok, so is there another browser that will let me do this?

Comment: Maybe it's better to close the browser everytime you open an url, so the next time it will be opened only in one tab again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox, if you go to about:config and set browser.link.open_newwindow to "1", that will cause a clicked link that would open in a new window or tab to stay in the current tab. I'm not sure if this applies to calls from 3rd-party apps, but it might be worth a try.

Of course, this will now apply to everything you do in firefox (though ctrl + click will still open links in a new tab)

Comment: Which file are you exactly talking about?  I was unable to find an about: config .  keep me posted, thanks for the help.

Comment: Open firefox, and type "about:config" (without the quotes) into the address bar, and hit enter. From there you can search for browser.link.open_newwindow with the "filter" bar.